# Highlight specific text in DBGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm performing a query and displaying returned data in dbgrid.

I would like to highlight the items matching the search criteria. Something like:

Search by : "**test**"

In DBGrid, returned data would be .

```
ID     Return
1      This is a **test**
2      **Test**ing
```

The goal here is no doubt about querying data. But how to highlight specific text in DBGrid?

Important: only the specific part of the text should be highlighted.

NOTE: The information presented is to make it clear, not corresponding exactly to reality.

Comment: That's not possible in the standard DBGrid. And questions asking about another component are off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic]. We're not the component shopping network.

Comment: You can in theory, by setting Default Drawing to false and drawing the cell yourself using the OnDrawColumnCell and/or OnDrawDataCell events, but that is a fair amount of work at quite a low level. The grid itself can't do it.

Comment: the DevExpress gridview does this right out of the box, but its not cheap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KenWhite. But my goal was to solve the issue, and not necessarily buy a component, could be a freeware or an intelligent answer as did ValMarinov. Anyway, I removed the part of the text that would be off-topic ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This procedure highlight  `FilterText' in DbGrid

```
procedure HighlightCellText(AGrid :TDbGrid; const ARect : TRect; AColumn : TColumn;  FilterText : string; AState:TGridDrawState ;
  BkColor : TColor = clYellow; SelectedBkColor : TColor = clGray);
var
  HlRect : TRect;
  Position : Integer;
  HlText, FilterColName,DisplayText: string;
  i, offset : Integer;
begin
   DisplayText := Acolumn.Field.AsString;
   Position := Pos(AnsiLowerCase(FilterText), AnsiLowerCase(DisplayText){  AnsiLowerCase(AColumn.DisplayText)});
   if Position > 0 then
   begin
     // set highlight area
     case AColumn.Alignment of
       taLeftJustify:  HlRect.Left := ARect.Left + AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(Copy(DisplayText, 1, Position-1)) + 1;
       taRightJustify: begin
         Offset := AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(Copy(DisplayText, 1,1)) - 1;
         HlRect.Left :=  (ARect.Right - AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(DisplayText)-offset) + AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(Copy(DisplayText, 1, Position-1));
       end;
       taCenter: begin
         Offset := ((ARect.Right - ARect.Left) div 2) - (AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(DisplayText) div 2) - (AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(Copy(DisplayText, 1,1)) - 2);

         HlRect.Left := (ARect.Right - AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(DisplayText)- offset) + AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(Copy(DisplayText, 1, Position-1));
       end;
     end;

     HlRect.Top := ARect.Top + 1;
     HlRect.Right := HlRect.Left +AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(Copy(DisplayText, Position, Length(FilterText))) + 1 ;
     HlRect.Bottom := ARect.Bottom - 1;

     //check for  limit of the cell
     if HlRect.Right > ARect.Right then
       HlRect.Right := ARect.Right;

     // setup the color and draw the rectangle in a width of the matching text
     if gdSelected in AState then
       AGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := SelectedBkColor
     else
       AGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := BkColor;

     AGrid.Canvas.FillRect(HlRect);

     HlText := Copy(DisplayText,Position, Length(FilterText));
     AGrid.Canvas.TextRect(HlRect,HlRect.Left + 1,HlRect.Top + 1, HlText);
   end;
end;
```

Use it in DbGrid.OnDrawColumnCell event :

For example highlight text is "ro".

```
procedure TForm6.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
 begin
   HighlightCellText(TDBGrid(Sender),Rect, Column,'ro',State);
end;
```

The result :

[image]

Edit :

[A litle demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGKSDT5eSPA&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Can you provide a demo of using this where the user types a search phrase in an edit control and the grid highlights the phrase (without scrolling the grid)? The only way I can see to do it would be to invalidate the entire grid, which is going to cause some ugly flickering.

Comment: Thank you so much Val Marinov! The given method works perfectly , without any issues.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok. Here is the demo. Is it enough? : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGKSDT5eSPA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Yep. :-) Very nicely done. I'd have to test the flickering issue with real data (more columns, more rows than what can be displayed in the grid), but it seems to work well. Thanks. :-)