# How to highlight one word in text in DBGRID

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Good afternoon, tell me how to remake or do? It is necessary to highlight the given word in bold. Just as it stands out in color: [Highlight specific text in DBGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873729/highlight-specific-text-in-dbgrid#)
Thank you very much

Comment: Exactly like in the accepted answer to your linked question - just manipulate `AGrid.Canvas.Font.Style` instead of `AGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color`. E.g. set it to `[]` or `[fsBold]`, respectively.

Comment: The linked post shows you how to do **exactly** what you're asking, including a sample `OnDrawColumnCell` event handler that demonstrates. I don't understand the point of asking how to do exactly what the post you linked that tells you how to do..